# passport js req.user not available after req.login

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, express

I am trying to setup my passport sessions correctly. I have gotten to the point where, after a user signs up - I execute `req.login()` and then I have a console message, `console.log(req.user)`. It returns:

`{ email: 'xxxx', password: 'xxxx', id: 0 }`

So it seems as if, right after the user is created, `req.user` is available. However, when a user logs in, I have this route:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', { failureRedirect: '/login'}),
      function(req, res) {
         console.log(req.user);
         res.redirect('/users');
      }
);
```

That console message (from the post call) returns:

```
{ id: null,
  email: 'xxxxx',
  password: 'xxxxx' }
```

As you can see - upon login - it redirects to `/users` - this is my get request:

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.user);
  res.render('partials/profile.html');
});
```

That console message returns `undefined` - so `req.user` is not being passed. Furthermore, if I examine the session with `console.log(req.session)` I get:

```
{ cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: true },
  passport: {} }
```

So you can see - there is no passport user in the cookie, it is an empty set.

Where am I going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: have you defined a session storage?

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem, and I just set a session name to the user's name in the login post. Then I could get it in the rest of the application.

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', { failureRedirect: '/login'}),
  function(req, res) {
     console.log(req.user);
     req.session.user = req.user;
     res.redirect('/users');
  }
);
```

So you can access that anywhere.

Comment: cool workaround - i actually fixed it...I'm not sure how, but I think when i did app.use(session({secret: "my secret:", cookie: secure})); or something like that - the cookie part was messing everything up, i think when i removed that it started working...thanks for your input...neat idea.

Comment: even i had the exact same problem. I had set cookie expiration in session, after removing it, auth started to work again. is it a bug in passport?

Comment: @ewizard Did you remove every mention of the cookies? Could you show me what exactly you did?

Comment: @DatBassie this was a while ago so i cant remember exactly nor do i remember what project i was working on...but i think i just removed `cookie: secure` - and then did whatever was necessary with the rest of the code related to the cookies to make sure it would execute...sorry...i dont remember exactly though.